# How is the color for the "Looking for a job?" ad chosen?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs, sidebar

Is there any difference in "Looking for a job?" ad and how the color is being chosen?

> [image]
>   *<sup>Image procured from the question [Is the color code for job ad based on any logic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/324271/692942)</sup>*

Because sometimes they are in orange and sometimes in blue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an A/B test.

[Is careers advertisement block being a-b tested?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230452/167646)

> Yes, like many sites we sometimes conduct A/B tests like this. Right now, on Stack Overflow, some people will indeed see an orange version of the Careers ad in the sidebar, and other people will see a blue version.

[For the love of god, please just pick a color for the job postings and stick with it!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234086/167646)

> Part of this was also discussed in the [recent podcast](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/05/podcast-59-hes-one-of-those-science-ists/), if you're interested in that sort of a thing, and simply using the colours seems to have a significant effect. So more than likely you'll have to put up with it for a while until they settle on a final result.

Comment: BTW I like the Orange more

Comment: How long will this test run? How are the results so far?

Comment: Bret Copeland has responded to these questions here : http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324286/4074148