# Is the color code for job ad based on any logic?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs, advertising

In the sidebar I'm seeing the **blue** and **orange** colored border for job advertisement.

Is the color code based on logic or simply a random color change for each job ad?

> [image]

Comment: the logic of [tangerine trees and marmalade skies](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eKXfqpg-Q-k)?

Comment: @AakashM the possible duplicate says, It's an A/B test - but it started May 2014, over two years ago - are they testing that long?

Comment: It may be a dup but I prefer this question, it's got more detail and a nice visual *(might have to tinker with the other question)*.

Comment: Apparently, teal and orange [are everywhere](http://theabyssgazes.blogspot.nl/2010/03/teal-and-orange-hollywood-please-stop.html).

Comment: @gnat "_This video contains content from UMG_MK, who has blocked it in your country on copyright grounds_". Maybe some transcription, huh? :> :> :>

Comment: @trejder you gotta google for that phrase (and pay attention to images for it)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

A long time ago, orange and blue were part of an A/B test. Actually, it was a four-way test which also featured a grey header and a "Careers 2.0" logo (the previous standard). Orange and blue performed the best, and roughly equal to each other, so we kept them both.

There are tag-themed job ads which have a dedicated color scheme per tag, but the other headers "Work from anywhere", "Looking for a job?", and "Jobs near you" all use the orange and blue. Which one you get on a particular request is completely random (50/50 chance).

By the way, the specific ads you screenshotted *are* part of an A/B test, but the *colors* are not.

Comment: I also get Gold/Yellow boxes sometimes... Why is that?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker they're probably python ads. As I said, tag-themed ads have their own dedicated colors.

Comment: For what it's worth, I much prefer the left ad's style.

Comment: Is "crossover" also some sort of test as well to see who responds to job ads for remote working at ridiculously low salaries?

Comment: @Rich: Some of them have really competitive salaries, if you cancel out the degree of Big Brotherism they want to expose you to.

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question, but what exactly do you mean by "A/B test"?

Comment: @kv.333 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A/B_testing Basically trying multiple variations of something at the same time and seeing which one, if any, performs the best.

Comment: @BretCopeland Thanks, I had thought it was just a StackOverflow thing.